# Download attribute allowing .html in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

The following code will download htmlTest.html in Chrome, but when run in Firefox will download htmlTest.html.pdf
Why does firefox add .pdf? I want to download .html as specified.

```html
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="download()">Download html file</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function download() {
        var element = document.createElement("a");
        var inshtml = `hello world`;
        element.setAttribute(
          "href",
          "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(inshtml)
        );
        element.setAttribute("download", "htmlTest.html");

        element.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        element.click();

        document.body.removeChild(element);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for FireFox. Firefox ignores the extension but looks for the MIME type.
e.g. this is where the mime type is set:

```
        element.setAttribute(
          "href",
          "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(inshtml)
        );
```

The change to make in my case to download a .html file I need to change the mime type (set after data: ) like so:

```
        element.setAttribute(
          "href",
          "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(inshtml)
        );
```

Mozilla explicitely states this at this link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types

And here is the key quote:

> Important: Browsers use the MIME type, not the file extension, to
>   determine how to process a URL, so it's important that web servers
>   send the correct MIME type in the response's Content-Type header. If
>   this is not correctly configured, browsers are likely to misinterpret
>   the contents of files and sites will not work correctly, and
>   downloaded files may be mishandled.

It is nice of Mozilla to speak for other browsers, though incorrectly in this case as other browsers don't change the explicitly given extension when downloading .html files.

Comment: You can ask a question and answer your own question but you can't vote yourself up! That is not fair. Well thanks for sharing this interesting behaviour of Firefox, hoping not to come across with this issue because i don't think i will remember it lol

Answer (score 0):

It is due to missing required html tags. Some Firefox releases actually ignore the whole document when tags are missing (Firefox developer edition 2020 release). Anyways I tried the code bellow and it is downloading .html on all browsers. If your Firefox still downloading as pdf, that means it is configured to do so. Make sure your firefox is configured to download html page as .html If you can do the configuration, may be you should reinstall a new browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="download()">Download html file</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function download() {
        var element = document.createElement("a");
        var inshtml = `hello world`;
        element.setAttribute(
          "href",
          "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(inshtml)
        );
        element.setAttribute("download", "htmlTest.html");

        element.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        element.click();

        document.body.removeChild(element);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine on Mac but I am having mixed results on Windows. A fresh install on Windows 7 with current firefox version 70, will return htmlTest.html.txt, a fresh install on Windows 10 will give htmlTest.html.pdf, a fresh install on Windows Server 2012r2  will give the correct file.